# Problem with QuickSort algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

i wrote i quicksort algorithm in c# but it has a problem,when i compile it,it doesnt work in some conditions for example when i enter number 12,32,11 in textbox6 to sort, it gives out of range error when i go to trace it, debugger shows that num[] took nums[0]=12,nums[1]=11,nums[2]=1

**Edited:**
i changed the while condition and it know doesnt give out of range error but when the input is 12,32,11 output 11,12,1

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] x = textBox6.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[x.Length];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < x.Length; counter++)
        {
            nums[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(x[counter]);
        }

        int i = 0;
        int  j = nums.Length;
        int pivot = nums[0];
        do 
        {
            do 
            {
                    i++;
            }
                  while ((i < nums.Length) && (nums[i] < pivot));
            do
                {
                    j--;
                }
while (nums[j]>pivot);
            if (i < j)
            {
                int temp = i;

                nums[i] = nums[j];
                nums[j] = temp;

            }

        }while(i<j);
        int temp1 = nums[0];
        nums[0] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp1;
        int pivotpoint = j;
        string QuickSort = "";
        foreach (var n in nums)
           QuickSort += n.ToString() + ",";
        textBox5.Text = QuickSort;

    }
```

Comment: perhaps you should post the complete code... Anyway, implementing a quick sort in a button event handler doesn't seem like a very good idea...

Comment: 1) You didn't post your complete loop. 2) I see no recursion. So how is this supposed to be quick-sort?

Comment: i edited my question and paste complete code

Comment: @Thomas: This is most likely a student's code, and apparently an assignment, so the event handler is probably the best place in such a case :) (although it should certainly be refactored).

Comment: First things first, is there a problem in the Quicksort or already in the decoding of the Textbox text?

Comment: @Henk Holterman:now the problem is in QuickSort,thanks

Comment: @arash, If this a homework tag it as homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `i` isn't being bounds-checked in your do-while loop. `i` will get incremented beyond the end of your `nums` array. Try modifying the while condition thus:

```
while ((i<nums.Length) && (nums[i]<pivot))
```

Of course you could simply use `Array.Sort(nums);`

Comment: This is most likely a student's code, trying to learn how to implement the quicksort algorithm, so he probably shouldn't be using `Array.Sort`.

Comment: @Hosam Aly: As we aren't *allowed* to tag questions as homework any more, I have to consider any question as non-homework. Either way, my purpose here is to answer the question not to ensure that their homework assignment is completed correctly. What is ironic is that the question was edited **after** my answer and still the OP has two while conditionals with no bounds checking.

Comment: @Lazarus:Excuse me sir,but i just completed my codes and didnt do anything else.i didnt change my code as you said because i thaught your answer may change when you see the complete code

Comment: @arash: Fair enough. Have you tried adding bounds checking to the while loops?

Comment: @Lazarus:no,because i didnt understand completly where should i change, im a collegian and i m writing this code to understand it,is this crime?

Comment: @Lazarus:i changed the code code as you said and it know doesnt give out of range error but when the input is 12,32,11 output 11,12,1

Comment: @Lazarus:would you help me more?thanks for your helps and sorry for my mistakes

Comment: @arash: After single stepping through your code I've found the key mistake. The line `int temp = i;` should be `int temp = nums[i];`, after that your original code works. I'm still not comfortable with the unbounded while loops but that's up to you. Making mistakes is not a crime, not stepping through the code (or at least rereading it) when you have an error (even if it's on paper) is.

Comment: @arash: I'm glad to help and I hope that you can take away from this that development involves a lot of stepping laboriously through code you are **sure** is right. We've all been there and done it.